# Subscript out of range (run time error 9)

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I have adapted a piece of code which is meant to colour several pie charts (and slices within them) according to cells in a workbook which can be coloured.

```
 Sub SetColorScheme(cht As Chart, i As Long)

    Dim y_off As Long, rngColors As Range
    Dim x As Long

    y_off = i Mod 10
    'this is the range of cells which has the colors you want to apply
    Set rngColors = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("colors").Range("A1:C1").Offset(y_off, 0)

    With cht.SeriesCollection(1)
        'loop though the points and apply the corresponding fill color from the cell
        For x = 1 To .Points.Count
            .Points(x).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = _
                             rngColors.Cells(x).Interior.Color
        Next x
    End With

End Sub
```

The problem is that I get the error Subscript out of Range (Run time error 9) when I try compiling the piece. Does somebody have any suggestions what could cause this behaviour? 
I have in total 8 pie charts so I also tried to enter i Mod 8 instead Mod 10 this hasn't changed the error. Is the error in connection the the other sub (the piece which generates the pie charts (since this sub is only colouring them?)Could soembody make any suggestions?

Comment: I am sure @Joe has already answered your question. Now looking at this from a different perspective `when I try compiling the piece.` And `Is the error in connection the the other sub`: There is a difference between compiling and executing a code. If you are using `Debug~~>Compile VBA Project` (COMPILING) and you are getting an error then yes, the error could be somewhere else. Contd...

Comment: If you are EXECUTING the code (by pressing F5 or Run menu) then you need to check which line is giving you the error. The major difference between VBA compiling and other computer language compiling is that with any new compilation a stand-alone EXE or DLL file is not generated after the compilation.

Comment: I should have mentioned that the error is in line Set rngColors = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("colors").Range("A1:C1").Offset(y_off, 0) could you have a look at my comment below (to the answer). I really dont know what is cuasing the error

Answer (score 1):

> Subscript out of range (run time error 9)
>
> I should have mentioned that the error is in line Set rngColors = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("colors").Range("A1:C1").Offset(y_off, 0) could you have a look at my comment below (to the answer). I really dont know what is cuasing the error – Johannes Graulich 9 hours ago

Two reasons that I can think of

1. You don't have a sheet with the name "Colors"
2. If you do visually see a sheet named "Colors", then check if there is a leading or trailing space in the name. You can either double click the sheet name in the tab and then check or you can make that sheet active and then use

   `Debug.print Len(Activesheet.Name)`

in a procedure or use the below in Immediate window to check

```
?Len(Activesheet.Name)
```

If you get more than 5 then that means you have a leading or trailing space.

Comment: that reall worked ! Could ou maybe tell me how I coudl read the range (which is the moment stated in the code) read froma seperate cell in the worksheet in which the colours were present?

Comment: Do you have a fixed range from where the colors are picked up or is it a dynamic range?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is accessing

```
rngColors.Cells(x)
```

where `x` loops from 1 to the number of points in a series.

Your range only has `y_off` cells.

So if any series has more than `y_off` points, you'll get a subscript out of range error.

Get your debugger out!

Comment: okay...does this mean that if I have 8 charts with three sections each (24 slices which I want to colour in total) which means 24 points in the series which number would I have to write behing the i Mod (that ascirbes a value to they y_off variable? Is it 24? Moreover, do I have to adjust the range accordingly? In the moment there are only three cells in the range (A1-C1)

Comment: @JohannesGraulich Sure, I noticed your comment is nearly 4 lines long.